# using media queries to manipulate jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I am having a difficult time with this jQuery accordion. I want to display the content using a jQuery accordion for mobile platforms and destroy the accordion on larger screen sizes. Everything is working fine except for two issues.

1. The accordion is destroyed only when the document window is re-sized and not destroyed on when the document loads.
2. once the accordion is destroyed I cant make the accordion work again when I resize the document window to mobile sizes.

here's some code:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="content-fill">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="testimonials col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <h1>section 1</h1>
                                <p>this is a paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="social col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                <h1>section 2</h1>
                                <div class="social-wrap">
                                    <a class="twitter-timeline" width="100%" data-chrome="transparent noscrollbar" href="https://twitter.com/xxxxxx" data-widget-id="383311602641952769">Tweets by @xxxxxx</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                <h1>section 3</h1>
                                <p>this is a paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  // <![CDATA[
     var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); $(document).ready(function()
    { 

        $('.content').addClass('accordion');

        $(window).resize(function() {
            if ($('.social').css('float') == 'left')    {
                $('.content').accordion('destroy');
            } else if($('.social').css('float') == 'none')   {
                $('.content').accordion('enable');
            }
        });

         $(".accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            header: "h1",
            heightStyle: "fill",
            });

            //getter variables
            var collapsible = $(".accordion").accordion("option","collapsible");
            var header = $(".accordion").accordion("option","header");
            var heightStyle = $(".accordion").accordion("option","heightStyle");

            $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 4000, cycle: true }); 

        }); // ]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `destroy` with `disable` and add a handler also to `load` event:

```
function accordionSwitch() {
    if ($('.social').css('float') == 'left')    {
        $('.content').accordion('disable');
    } else if($('.social').css('float') == 'none')   {
        $('.content').accordion('enable');
    }
}

$(window).on('resize load', accordionSwitch);
```

[Accordion documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy) says that `destroy` method

> *removes the accordion functionality **completely**. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.*

Comment: using the on() resize and load worked and solved part of the problem as well as using disable. I added a couple of other functions to further solve this problem. thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

so why you dont use media queries to hide the accordion on large screens and display it on "small" screens?

```
@media (max-width: 797px) {
    . accordion {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

and your default style is

```
.accordion {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Im not using media queries directly because im using bootstrap. In bootstrap, your float behavior is directly linked to your media breakpoints. It would make more sense to use float so that thr behavior of my functions maych the behavior og my content. Sounds wierd but it works

Answer (score 0):

Don't enable and destroy your accordion. Just run different functions depending on the screen size. That will be the easiest solution for you, and then you don't have to run a function on the screen resizing.